# Alternative to UML class diagrams for non-software context

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram, sysml

For a presentation I would like to show the relationship between machines of our company. There are basic machines and specialized machines. The specialized machines can do everything the basic machine can do.
I would like to show this relationship in the form of a class diagram in UML using the generalization arrow. However, I am afraid that UML class diagrams are very software specific.

Are there alternatives for general contexts? Maybe SysML?

---

Edit:

Here is a simplified diagram which is in principle very similar to the diagram I would present:

[image]

I have no data types for the attributes here, because in my opinion they make no sense. Would you still let it pass as UML? Or other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though SysML is targeted on modeling hardware, it is using similar language elements like UML. And of course it can model hard- and software - like UML.

Actually you can (almost) show SysML using a profile in UML. You can find both the SysML spec and the UML profile at https://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/1.2/About-SysML/

You should not be afraid to use UML if it's at hand. You can describe anything (technical) using this language.

RE your edit (this might start going to far, so if anything else arises ask a new question):

- `Cooling` should be a class of its own. You'd have some abstract cooling device which can do general cooling (of the attached device). You then use specialized coolings that can do more (or less) fancy stuff. An ice bucket would be a simple one. And a Linde machine could come with lots of additional features.
- That with the `levels` seems ok. Note that there's a naming convention where you start classes with upper and attributes/operations with lower case. So one back you'd better write `cooling: Cooling`
- About the memory. The way you did it is not good. It's not overriding anything in that case. Also `memory` as a general attribute sounds like a flawed design. Memory is too general. Think about what kind of settings should be allowed and probably put these in an enumeration. That definitely needs a bit of brain power to get it right.

As said, these are a few loose thoughts. Making a design is good for an afternoons workshop (as a start).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Since you meant, UML would be ok, I extended my question again by a diagram and new questions. I would be happy if you could also refer to it.

Comment: Just see my additions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, that's more than I had hoped for.